# How to minimize route time in verilog code

Tags: verilog, hdl

i wrote verilog code, when i synthesis it, timing results give a high delay and low frequency... i find the max delay is from routing time in one module

> Total                    100.204ns (23.729ns logic, 76.475ns route)

the module which cases the delay showed below, how can i optimize it to minimize the delay and improve the performance

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module ALU(aa,result,clk,ready,out,r1,r2,r3,start);


output reg [87:0] result;
output reg[9:0]out;

input [87:0] aa;
input clk,start;
output reg ready;  /// ready to load from alu to array ... from memory to array
input [87:0] r1,r2,r3;
reg [87:0] a;
//reg [87:0]a;



always@(start or aa or r1 or r2 or r3  )
begin
  if(start)
    ready=0;

  a=aa;


  if((r1[65:60]==a[83:78])&&(a[8:6]==0)) begin
    a[38:29]=r1[59:50];  // current result from other alu's
  end
  else if((r1[65:60]==a[77:72])&&(a[5:3]==0)) begin
    a[28:19]=r1[59:50];
  end
  else if((r1[65:60]==a[71:66])&&(a[2:0]==0)) begin
    a[18:9] =r1[59:50];
  end 

  if((r2[65:60]==a[83:78])&&(a[8:6]==0)) begin
    a[38:29]=r2[59:50];
  end
  else if((r2[65:60]==a[77:72])&&(a[5:3]==0)) begin
    a[28:19]=r2[59:50];
  end
  else if((r2[65:60]==a[71:66])&&(a[2:0]==0)) begin
    a[18:9] =r2[59:50];
  end 

  if((r3[65:60]==a[83:78])&&(a[8:6]==0)) begin
    a[38:29]=r3[59:50];
  end
  else if((r3[65:60]==a[77:72])&&(a[5:3]==0)) begin
    a[28:19]=r3[59:50];
  end
  else if((r3[65:60]==a[71:66])&&(a[2:0]==0)) begin
    a[18:9] =r3[59:50];
  end 

  //$display(a[38:29], a[28:19], a[18:9]);
  ready=1;
  result[87:0]=a[87:0];

  if (a[40:39]==0)                 // addition
    result[59:50]=a[38:29]+a[28:19];

  else if (a[40:39]==1)           // multiplication
    result[59:50]=a[38:29]*a[87:84];

  else if(a[40:39]==2)             // mul-add
    result[59:50]=(a[38:29]*a[87:84])+a[28:19]+a[18:9];
  else 
    result[59:50]=0;

  out=result[59:50];

end

endmodule
```

Comment: You are using `ready` for which purpose? As you are just switching it from 0 to 1 without any delay?

Comment: this signal is enable signal for another module when finish calculations in this module

Comment: if i use a pipeline multiplier , will increase the frequency?

Comment: I dont think without delay in same always block, `ready` will work. You are describing hardware through verilog programming, not a software, which will execute sequentially.

Comment: `(a[38:29]*a[87:84])+a[28:19]+a[18:9]` is likely the primary performance offender because it consistent of 5 stages of addition plus xor overhead as well as the muxing overhead to determine `a`. It is hard to give advice without knowing the requirements. Is there a clock and what is the period? what is the maximum time to allowed to evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your static timing report post-synthesis and post-place and route to properly analyze what parts of your design are taking the most time and figure where to optimize. However, I'm going to suggest that the multiplier is contributing the bulk of your timing delay (as @Greg already mentioned).

If you are targeting an FPGA based design, then you should make use of one of the multiplier/DSP macros that are built into almost all FPGA designs these days. You can do this by directly instantiating the macro or by writing your code in such a way that the synthesis engine will pick up that you are wanting to infer one of these blocks. You'll need to consult the documentation for your particularly synthesis engine since you haven't specified what you are using here. Your synthesis tool should allow you to check the output netlist, preferably as a schematic to make sure that you are getting the DSP block instantiated.

You also should clock your design rather than making it all combinatorial and pipeline it to separate the multiplication operation and the addition operation. This will work very well with the FPGA DSP macro.

If you are targeting an ASIC rather than an FPGA, you would want to check how your synthesis engine deals with multipliers. There may be pragmas (instructions that are embedded in the code as comments which the synthesis engine recognizes) which can direct the synthesis engine as to what type of multiplier you want to implement. Once again, please at least pipeline the multiplication and addition operations.

You've written your code as completely combinatorial logic without any clocked elements. So the synthesis engine will probably not try to optimize timing, but will rather try to optimize area (i.e. the number of gates used) and not care about timing, unless you've clocked the design outside of this module.

Finally, make sure you heed @Karen Shaw's comments regarding your ready signal. Currently, all it will produce is a glitch, and since the timing on that signal is independent of the timing through the multiplier/adder, it won't do what you want. You need to clock the design and implement the ready signal in clocked logic. Remember, Verilog is not a programming language, it's a hardware description language. You are using code to describe actual logic gates, which are the output of your synthesis engine. If you can't imagine what your synthesis engine is going to produce, you probably won't get a usable design.

Comment: thank for u r advice ... the ready signal works correctly because it enables other module after the calculations finished....

Comment: As in the synthesis report ... the bulk delay is because multiplier , adder and mux in above module ...... how can i make fpga to use dsp multiplier ... its hard to convert from combinational to sequential code

Comment: If you want to design FPGAs or ASICs you need to learn how to code sequential logic--it's one of the most basic skills. The most simple explanation is that you use the positive edge of your clock in the always sensitivity list rather than all the combinatorial inputs. Then the results of all of your calculations will all be registered. Now you come to the second major skill--how to share resources. Multipliers take a lot of logic, but multiplexors not so much. So you want to have one multiplier and multiplex the inputs. Your code uses multiple multipliers and multiplexes the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if-else` to `case` statements. If else statements synthesize to priority encoders, that take up more routing logic and delay than case, which synthesizes to a n:1 multiplexer.